# What does resolving reference mean in Linker/Compiler?

Tags: c, compilation, linker

I don't understand fully why we need a linker. Compiler first turn the highlevel code to assembly, then this assembly code is translated to machine code. Everything we want(except which address to load this code) is present. Why needing a separate Linker module?
Assume my program is

```
printf("Hello Basic Question!");
```

this C code translates to bunch of assembly instructions. I don't understand when we say Linker resolves reference to `printf`. Can you elaborate please?
Does it mean in some library there is a mapping between `printf` and assembly instructions and linker simply pull that mapping out and replaces the `printf` with that?

Answer (score 3):

`printf` is a function that is not in your code, but in an object library.
`printf` calls some kernel functions to output your message.
The linker resolves references, extract object modules from libraries and add them to your executable. It also resolves references to call kernel functions and produce all data structures used by the OS `loader module` to allocate memory, load and execute your code.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful explanation. But I have a query. Then what does the pre-processor do? Doesn't it add the <stdio.h> where the printf() is defined and updates the source file?Then the new source file has the printf() defined in it and goes for compilation? I'm sorry if I'm asking an absurd and stupid question. I am new to this sections. Please bear with me.

Comment: @lU5er The preprocessor simply include another file in the main, and executes some **text transformation**, i.e. macro replacement (you may want read what wikipedia says here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). Specifically `<stdio.h>` include in your source all references to global variables and function prototypes for I/O functions as `printf`. The **linking** between your code and object library code and OS functions still remain at charge of the linker exactly as explained above. True for all compiled languages of course (linker use object modules and don't care of src language)